# Merging several videos with audio channel and without audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, encoding, merge

I need to merge very different videos into a one output video.
Input videos can have different resolutions, framerate, channels and so on.
So some videos can be **without audio channel** and should be merged with video **with audio channel**. I do not know beforehand if it is with or without audio channel 
So I use **ffmpeg** with -filter_complex to make videos the same frame size and next filter **concat** to merge them. 
(also I need to cut input videos but let me skip this part here)

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "withAudio.flv" -i "noAudio.mpg" \
-filter_complex \
    "[0:v]scale=1280:720, setsar=1/1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
    [1:v]scale=1280:720, setsar=1/1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
    [v0][0:a] [v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx264 -b 512k -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 128k  \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags faststart -y "result.mp4"
```

And in result I get an error about missing channel

```
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v]scale=1280:720, setsar=1/1
, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [1:v]scale=1280:720, setsar=1/1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[
v1];  [v0][0:a] [v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.
```

Full

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/xtendx/local --arch=x86 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --pkg-config=pkg-config --disable-pthreads --enable-w32threads --extra-libs=-lws2_32 --extra-libs=-lwinmm --extra-libs=-lgdi32 --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-debug --disable-indevs --disable-outdevs --disable-iconv --disable-bzlib --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-librtmp --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --disable-libxcb --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --disable-libxcb-shape --enable-decoder=prores_lgpl --disable-decoder=prores --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-openssl
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, flv, from 'withAudio.flv':
  Metadata:
    starttime       : 0
    totalduration   : 30
    totaldatarate   : 484
    bytelength      : 1846185
    canseekontime   : true
    sourcedata      : B4A7D0D44HH1361885066111689
    purl            :
    pmsg            :
    httphostheader  : r15---sn-1gi7zn7s.c.youtube.com
  Duration: 00:00:30.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 484 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 388 kb
/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 99 kb/s
Input #1, mpeg, from 'noAudio.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:29.96, start: 0.500000, bitrate: 8040 kb/s
    Stream #1:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:4
5 DAR 16:9], 8000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc


Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v]scale=1280:720, setsar=1/1
, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [1:v]scale=1280:720, setsar=1/1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[
v1];  [v0][0:a] [v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.
```

From the FFmpeg documentation for concat filter:

> ```
> The filter works on segments of synchronized video and audio streams.
> All segments must have the same number of streams of eachtype, 
> and that will also be the number of streams at output.
> ```

So how can I build the command to merge several videos **with different channels number** ?

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg is expecting an audio stream to pair with the 2nd video. Since there isn't one, you'll have to supply a dummy one.

Since you aren't sure if the inputs have audio, run this command for each input:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v copy \
-map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 1:a -shortest <output>
```

And then, with the processed files

```
ffmpeg.exe -i <input1> -i <input2> \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1280:720, setsar=1/1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]scale=1280:720, setsar=1/1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [v0][0:a] [v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 512k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-map "[a]" -acodec libfaac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 \
-movflags faststart -y "result.mp4"
```

Comment: Problem is that I do not know beforehand if video has sound or not. so I do not know what exactly stream should be replaced.

Comment: You'll have to probe each input and check for presence of `Audio`

Comment: Is there any chance to do this with one command?

Comment: Not that I know. But the edited workflow should work with agnostic inputs.

Comment: Thank you! This answer pointed me in the right direction for a problem I had to day related to scaling and combining videos of different sizes :)