# Use FFMpeg concat demuxer with multiple files with/without audio tracks

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm trying to combine multiple files with FFMpeg's concat demuxer. The issue is that some of these files don't have an audio track and others do and I don't know which do and which don't. For example:

- vid1.mp4 - no audio
- vid2.mp4 - has audio
- vid3.mp4 - no audio
- vidn.mp4 - no audio

All these .mp4 files are generated by me and are the output of an ffmpeg trim command. So the lifecycle of a file looks like this:
input-video -> trimming + other ffmpeg stuff -> output.mp4

The issue I'm, running into is that if a file that does not contain audio is the first in the concat list, the entire concatenated video does not have audio. But if the first file does have audio the rest do as well.

So my thinking is that I can add a silent audio track to to all the input videos (or if possible only to the videos that do not have audio at all) at the stage when I'm processing the input video (i.e. the trimming stage)

I'm not sure how to accomplish this though. Any ideas how to achieve this? I'm also open to using different methodologies, but a requirement for me is to use the concat demuxer.

Comment: All files will need to have an audio track, silent if not already present. See the first command at https://superuser.com/a/1044997/. Also see https://video.stackexchange.com/a/27740/

Comment: With regards to the first link that you sent me, it doesn't seem like the second command uses the concat demuxer. Would I be able to just replace that combine complex filter with a concat demuxer command?

Comment: Yes, provided all inputs have streams with same properties.

Comment: Since I'm performing commands on each input before the concat (trimming, etc.) I should be able to add the necessary commands to ensure the output is the same for each input. As far as I can tell, the required properties are, size, framerate, timebase, codecs. Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32603/